# Question about ModelMultipleChoiceField

Tags: python, django, postgresql

It so happened that I had to use arrays of PostgreSQL. In Django models do not have native support for arrays, so I used [django_arrayfields](https://github.com/aino/django-arrayfields). But for display in the admin should I use for the field hoprizontal_filter IntegerArrayField.

models.py

```
class Group(models.Model): 
    name = models.TextField()

class User(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()
    groups = IntegerArrayField()
```

admin.py

```
class GroupAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    groups = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
    queryset=Group.objects.all(), 
    label=('Select groups'),
    required=True,
    widget=FilteredSelectMultiple(
        ('groups'),
        False,
))

class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ('groups',)
    form = GroupAdminForm
```

As a result of this widget is displayed and works properly. But while maintaining writes can't adapt type 'QuerySet'.

Please HELP!!!

UPD:
Request information in the field POST variable groups has value which corresponds only to the last id of the selected group. Rather than an array as I expect.

Answer (score 1):

Can't help without a proper error/traceback.

For your updated point, remember that you need to do `request.POST.getlist(fieldname)` if you're expecting multiple values.

Comment: With the data in the POST I figured out there all right.

What kind of error / traceback you want to see?

Answer (score 0):

so, first we need separate the thins:

**admin.py**

```
 from .forms import GroupAdminForm
class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ('groups',)
    form = GroupAdminForm
```

**forms.py**

```
class GroupAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    groups = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
    queryset=Group.objects.all(), 
    label=('Select groups'),
    required=True,
    widget=FilteredSelectMultiple(
        ('groups'),
        False,
))
```

do this and post your trace error, it's hard to help without logs or error description.